# How to Activate sheet properly within workbook in function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, worksheet

I am trying to get the last column and last row for a given worksheet within my workbook. Below is the code I am using to get these values. This code works perfect (as in I get the correct number of col and rows) as long as I have clicked on a worksheet and then run the **Sub LastRowCol()**.

```
Function LastUsedRow_Find() As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells
    LastUsedRow_Find = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
End Function

Function LastUsedColumn_Find() As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells
    LastUsedColumn_Find = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Function

Sub LastRowCol()
  MsgBox "last row -> " & LastUsedRow_Find()
  MsgBox "last col -> " & LastUsedColumn_Find()
End Sub
```

But let's say I have multiple sheets for example. I am trying to pass the index of a sheet to the methods as shown below. I am then trying to Activate the sheet for the given index, since I'm using **ActiveSheet** a few lines later. Code runs with no exceptions But I am not getting the correct number of columns and rows anylonger in the msg box.

```
Function LastUsedRow_Find(wksIndex As Integer) As Integer
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wksIndex).Activate
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells
    LastUsedRow_Find = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
End Function

Function LastUsedColumn_Find(wksIndex As Integer) As Integer
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wksIndex).Activate
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells
    LastUsedColumn_Find = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Function

Sub LastRowCol()
    MsgBox "last row -> " & LastUsedRow_Find(1)
    MsgBox "last col -> " & LastUsedColumn_Find(1)
End Sub
```

Can someone please let me know what I may be doing wrong or what I may need to change? Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine for me. You are getting the last used row and the last used column. Not the same as Ctrl-End. You are getting the last row/column that actually has data.

Comment: which is working for you, the first version or second? As the first works for me too properly, but second does not return correct values

Comment: To debug it you need to see which cell it returns. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the index, why don't you pass the `Worksheet Object` instead.

```
Function LastUsedRow_Find(sh As Worksheet) As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then LastUsedRow_Find = rng.Row
End Function
```

Same should be done with your other function.
Also, I slightly modified it to handle blank sheets.
So above function will return the last row number if it is available and just empty if not.

Then call your function like this:

```
Sub LastRowCol()
    MsgBox "last row -> " & LastUsedRow_Find(Sheets("Sheet1"))
    MsgBox "last col -> " & LastUsedColumn_Find(Sheets("Sheet1"))
End Sub
```

Comment: I decided index, as I didn't know nor really care about the sheet name, just the counts.

Comment: @tony Then use index like this `LastUsedRow_Find(Sheets(1))`. This way, you wont have to worry about the function working explicitly on the correct worksheet in the background. Also you need to know how sheets are indexed.

Comment: +1 for using the objects.  If they hadn't included the Active* globals, we'd have a lot less questions here...

Comment: @L42 thanks for the input. One question as I am new to VB, why are you returning a variant rather than integer? If I'm just interested in the number does this matter or is variant a better choice? In that case I assume the variable holding the returned value must be of variant type as well.

Comment: @L42 tried to modify 'LastUsedColumn_Find()' as you suggested above but getting a 
**Run-time error '91': Object varibable or With block variable not set** when trying to Set the rng. Not sure why

Comment: @tony I used variant since it can handle any value (error, empty, integer, long). `In that case I assume the variable holding the returned value must be of variant type as well` No. That is another advantage of using a variant type. You can pass it in any variable type. As for your error, watch out for the `After` argument. It should be `sh.Cells(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the details. And yes my mistake didn't change code to `sh.Cells(1). `

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works fine, but here is a modified version that will `Debug.Print` the address of the found cell for the last row/column. I also don't activate the sheet as that's superfluous. Nor do I assign the entire workbook cells range to a variable, only the found result.

```
Function LastUsedRow_Find(wksIndex As Integer) As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wksIndex)
    Dim rgFound As Range
    Set rgFound = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    'return first row if worksheet is blank
    If rgFound Is Nothing Then
        LastUsedRow_Find = 1
    Else
        LastUsedRow_Find = rgFound.Row
        Debug.Print "Last row address: " & rgFound.Address
    End If

End Function

Function LastUsedColumn_Find(wksIndex As Integer) As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wksIndex)
    Dim rgFound As Range
    Set rgFound = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    'return first column if worksheet is blank
    If rgFound Is Nothing Then
        LastUsedColumn_Find = 1
    Else
        LastUsedColumn_Find = rgFound.Column
        Debug.Print "Last column address: " & rgFound.Address
    End If

End Function

Sub LastRowCol()
    MsgBox "last row -> " & LastUsedRow_Find(1)
    MsgBox "last col -> " & LastUsedColumn_Find(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Notice also that the functions are returning Long instead of Integer. This is necessary as Integer isn't large enough for 1,048,576 rows. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251684.aspx

Comment: looking at addresses. weird but addresses of cells are way off. So what I tried is I copied the data by going to cell(1,1) and CTRL+Shift+end which highlights all the data, copied that into new workbook and then ran it. Seemed to work fine. But origianl workbook gives me weird results :/

Comment: They may look like the wrong cells but have you tried selecting that cell and pressing [Delete] to delete the cell contents. Then run the macro again. You should get a different cell then. This means that although you think there is no data there, yet the cell is not really blank.